# Database Backup\Restore Not working properly

Tags: backup, sql

In my present SharePoint farm what we do is  create a web app and restore a previously saved backup of a site to the new one, this is usually done using the PowerShell site collection back\restore method. And later on the new site is customized by the developers.

Recently I had to copy a site in my production environment to my development , and this time i took the database base backup of my production site from the DB server and restored it to the development instance . After that I attached this DB to my site on development farm. But when i load my development site its not the exact site as my production site instead what I get is the template site which I used to create my production site earlier(may a year before). My present production site is highly customized and totally different from the template. I am used to  performing database backup\restore's on my farms and no before I had come across such a case.

what can be the problem. I am supposed to get the exact copy of a site when I do a DB backup\restore but the restored site am getting is the template that I used to create the site.

All my sharepoint farms are on version 15.0.4753.1000 and DB is 2014 STD

Comment: Couple of questions. How you customized your site, using designer or some custom code? How old you dev farm is? do you have old copy of that site collection already in dev farm( from previous restore)...this is most probably is the case? Are you backing up the correct db?

Comment: HI Waqas,                                                                                                                    The site is customized both using designer and custom codes, my DEV farm would be an year old same as my PROD. All my sites are restored copies (site collection using powershell)  of a template site. They are worked on at DEV farm and after the distinct customization they are DB restored to PROD farm.

Comment: By chance do you have the same site collection in your dev farm? How many web application in your farm and how many content DB attached to each web app, specially for the web app where u are attaching the db?

Answer (score 0):

You may have backed up the wrong database.
From Central Admin -> Manage Content databases, get the correct content DB name for your production web application and make sure that DB is backed up.
Before backing up it is good to set the DB to read only.
Before restore to Dev farm, make sure all the solutions in your Production farm are available in the dev farm as well.

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your replies but I have clearly mentioned that I am not new to DB backup\restore processes. I have backup-ed the exact DB that I want and not made any mistakes there.

Comment: You dont have to go into details of taking DB backups rather please help me with DB going corrupt. I am happy to fill you with any details needed for this.

Comment: You can run the Test-SPContentDatabase command on your database to check for issues with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. You are backing proper content database
2. Customisations that are made to file system you need to manually copy over

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your replies but I have clearly mentioned that I am not new to DB backup\restore processes. I have backup-ed the exact DB that I want and not made any mistakes there.                                                 Please tell me if you have any idea about what is making the DB corrupt